# How to enable higher CPU frequency on Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: lubuntu, cpu

I have a Dell Latitude D430 laptop and I am unable to get the CPU to scale up to it's max 1200MHz. I have installed the `indicator-cpufreq` tool and also the `cpufrequtils` package. However, my CPU is stuck at 800MHz. Running `cpufreq-info` gives some interesting information:

```
segin@darvos:/etc$ cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 007: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 1.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.20 GHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 800 MHz.
                  The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
  cpufreq stats: 1.20 GHz:46.82%, 800 MHz:53.18%  (647303)

analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 1.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.20 GHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 800 MHz.
                  The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
  cpufreq stats: 1.20 GHz:46.44%, 800 MHz:53.56%  (599777)
```

Now, if I attempt to set the CPU governor to another governor, the policy still specifies the same frequency range. Attempting to specify a new maximum frequency with `sudo cpufreq-set --related --max 1200MHz` gives no error but has no effect. Attempting `sudo cpufreq-set --related --min 1200MHz --max 1200MHz` generates the 'Error setting new values' error message. Removing `--related` does not change the outcome of each attempt.

How can I change the CPU scaling settings so that I can lock it to 1200MHz all day, every day? This laptop has a battery used well beyond it's lifespan, so it's always connected to a charger, and a 90W one at that.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you are connecting to a quality AC source. I had my machine plugged into a long extension cord, and that was par of the problem.

Next, assuming the Dell Bios is getting in the way, try this:

Edit /etc/default/grub

Add processor.ignore_ppc=1 to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line.

run sudo update-grub

Reboot the computer.

This is from http://www.woolie.co.uk/article/dell-laptop-stuck-800mhz-linux-fix/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

The system stubbornly reported 1.20 GHz - 1.20 GHz:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 2.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.20 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 1.20 GHz.
                  The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.20 GHz:0.78%, 2.20 GHz:64.67%, 2.10 GHz:0.01%, 2.00 GHz:0.01%, 1.90 GHz:0.01%, 1.80 GHz:0.01%, 1.70 GHz:18.33%, 1.60 GHz:0.01%, 1.50 GHz:0.01%, 1.40 GHz:0.02%, 1.30 GHz:0.01%, 1.20 GHz:16.13%  (158857)
```

Changing the governor made no difference:

```
parallel sudo cpufreq-set -c {} -g performance ::: {0..7}
parallel sudo cpufreq-set -c {} -g ondemand ::: {0..7}
```

Setting the upper and lower limits made no difference:

```
parallel sudo cpufreq-set -c {} -u 2200Mhz ::: {0..7}
parallel sudo cpufreq-set -c {} -d 1200Mhz ::: {0..7}
```

But what *did* make a difference was *changing* the lower limit:

```
parallel sudo cpufreq-set -c {} -d 1300Mhz ::: {0..7}
```

Then suddenly everything worked. I could even set the lower limit back to 1200MHz.